# How can I detect hold but not press

Tags: flutter

I have a button and little animation. When I click the button (I'm holding it) I want to see the press animation. When I stop pressing the button, it becomes a red box again.
There is no change when I hold it down in its current state.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color color = Colors.red;
  double w = 100.0;
  double h = 100.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            width: w,
            height: h,
            color: color,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.blue;
              h = 75.0;
              w = 125.0;
            });
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
              setState(() {
                color = Colors.red;
                h = 100.0;
                w = 100.0;
                print("pressed");
              });
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your `Container` with `InkWell` or `InkResponse`. Then you can set `hoverColor`, `highlightColor` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AnimatedContainer` and then use `Duration` Property to give it animation effect. After that you can replace `onTap` with `onLongPress` and the magic happens :)

Below is the code which I edited:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color color = Colors.red;
  double w = 100.0;
  double h = 100.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            width: w,
            height: h,
            color: color,
          ),
          onLongPress: () {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.blue;
              h = 75.0;
              w = 125.0;
            });
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
              setState(() {
                color = Colors.red;
                h = 100.0;
                w = 100.0;
                print("pressed");
              });
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```